# How to create weights based on position of a comma separated field and unnest the column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this: weights based on number of path in the second field.

```
ID                  path                       weights 
| 1               YouTube,Newsletter,Social     0.3
| 2               YouTube,Newsletter            0.5
| 3               YouTube                        1
```

I want to create more weights for first and last position and average the rest to paths in the middle. How do I do it? 
I want the table to look like this:

```
ID                  path                       weights 
| 1                 Social                      0.4
| 1                 YouTube                     0.4
| 1                 Newsletter                  0.2
| 2                 YouTube                     0.5
| 2                 Newsletter                  0.5
| 3                 YouTube                      1
```

Thanks! and let me know if I can help clarify more.

Comment: And where does the 0.4 come from?

Comment: im using mysql. 0.4 is more of an arbitrary assigned weights. 1st and last position will each get 40%, the rest in the middle will get the rest. so if the path looks like  YouTube,Newsletter,Search, Social. it should be YouTube (0.4) ,Newsletter(0.1),Search(0.1), Social(0.4).

Comment: Did you try something to solve your issue? as a start did you try with `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`?

Comment: i just misread. I have not tried subtring_index () to solve the issue

Comment: @Erica Shi From your most recently deleted comment 'yes. as a start i used group_concat' - so is the data shown not your start point?

Comment: no. the original data is in the format of    -                                                                
 ID                  path                       visit date 
| 1                 Social                        07-21-2019
| 1                 YouTube                     08-21-2019
| 1                 Newsletter                   09-01-2019

Comment: @EricaShi: would you please edit your question to show what the original data looks like? It seems like starting from the original data would be much easier than operating on the aggregated dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,weights,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Path                       
FROM
(
SELECT ID,weights,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Path,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   YourTableName
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

You can use this Query....Here I'm using Sql server...

Comment: No you cannot non of these features are available in mysql

Comment: The question tagged with `MySQL` tag not `SQL Server`. and that can be done easily with `STRING_SPLIT()` without casting as `XML`.